# Problem with creating an entity with Jhipster

Tags: jhipster, ajv

I'm using the latest version of jHipster (7) and I have a problem when I try to generate an entity with jhipster entity command. It says that a node-module is missing :

Cannot find module 'ajv/dist/compile/context'

And when I look at some project I've generated with an other version of jHipster, I can find this file. I think it's a pb with the new version as it's the first time I have this pb...

I tried to find the missing file on internet, but i don't find it.

Comment: Known issue: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/14492 the workaround is in issue comments

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for the workaround for this issue in jhipster version 7 :
you can find it here :

**Workarounds:**

```
1. npm install -g npm@latest (Or just downgrade npm version at pom.xml)

2. Recreate package-lock/node_modules

3. rm -rf package-lock.json node_modules

4. npm install
```

source : [comment github link](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/14492#issuecomment-809298321)